# After using any_value also getting error Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am using group by clause in mysql query and getting error of nonaggregated column,I can't disable full_ group_by from preveliges  because I am using share hosting so don't have access to this so I tried alternate way ANY_VALUE however using this also I am getting same error:
Mysql query

```
SELECT any_value(o.booking_id), any_value(o.id)id,any_value(u.name) as user_name,  
FROM orders o 
    JOIN items ON items.id=o.product_id 
    JOIN users u ON u.id=o.user_id 
    JOIN payment p ON p.booking_id=o.booking_id 
WHERE o.status =0 
GROUP BY o.booking_id 
ORDER BY o.id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not select the column `o.id` so you can't sort by `o.id`.

But it does select and return the column `any_value(o.id)` which you can use:

```
ORDER BY any_value(o.id)
```

or its alias:

```
ORDER BY id
```

Also there is no need to use `any_value()` for the column(s) that are included in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT o.booking_id, any_value(o.id)id,any_value(u.name) as user_name 
FROM orders o 
    JOIN items ON items.id=o.product_id 
    JOIN users u ON u.id=o.user_id 
    JOIN payment p ON p.booking_id=o.booking_id 
WHERE o.status =0 
GROUP BY o.booking_id 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: just now I use your query in phpmyadmin but getting same error

Comment: @user_1234 Check the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d02ce9051bc5b9221ce09d95734d4dd4. The query is syntactically correct, apart from a comma that I will remove after user_name.

Comment: thanks it is working previously In one column I missed any_value and this caused same error, now it is working because I followed your query.